# How sklearn.pipeline works, in manually?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

Currently, I am working on the sklearn.pipeline which is just wonderful Here is an example:

```
model = make_pipeline(TfidfVectorizer(), MultinomialNB())
model.fit(train.data, train.target)
labels = model.predict(test.data)
```

(*data is from `train = fetch_20newsgroups(subset='train', categories=categories`))
with `categories= ['talk.religion.misc', 'soc.religion.christian', 'sci.space','comp.graphics']`

However, my understanding is just still very vague. I would like to ask that if we do it step by step without pipeline how it could be. Here is just what I am trying to do but it failed.

```
from sklearn.datasets import fetch_20newsgroups
Categories = ['talk.religion.misc', 'soc.religion.christian', 'sci.space','comp.graphics']
train = fetch_20newsgroups(subset='train', categories=categories)`

from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
model1=TfidfVectorizer()
X=model1.fit_transform(train.data)

from sklearn.naive_bayes import MultinomialNB
model2=MultinomialNB
model2.fit(....)
```

At this far, I just don't know what to do next because the shape of `X`is not suitable for `model2`.

For your further information of this, go to the book from [this](https://tanthiamhuat.files.wordpress.com/2018/04/pythondatasciencehandbook.pdf) link 
at page (406/548)

*** *Please pardon for my silly question. I know I can do it by using pipeline but just want to try*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are almost there! you need to use `MultinomialNB()` instead of `MultinomialNB`.

Try the following procedure.

```
from sklearn.datasets import fetch_20newsgroups
Categories = ['talk.religion.misc', 'soc.religion.christian', 'sci.space','comp.graphics']
train = fetch_20newsgroups(subset='train', categories=categories)


from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
model1=TfidfVectorizer()
X=model1.fit_transform(train.data)

from sklearn.naive_bayes import MultinomialNB
model2=MultinomialNB()
model2.fit(X, train.target)
model2.predict(model1.transform(test.data))

# array([2, 1, 1, ..., 2, 1, 1])
```

Comment: You save the date mate !